# How can I change the ftp-code that i have access to a specific folder

Tags: android, ftp

I'm working on a FTP-project to send a picture taken by camera to a FTP-Server.

Now it's possible, that my picuture will be saved in folder: /sdcard/ftp/

How I have to change the code from my FTPActivity, that the files in the folder will be send?

Hope somebody can give me an example. Or post the changed code. That would be very helpful for me.

Here my FTP-Client-Code:

```
package de.android.datenuebertragung;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;

public class FTPManager extends Activity{
    FTPClient con = new FTPClient();{


    try
    {
        con.connect("host");
        if (con.login("user", "password"))
        {

            con.enterLocalPassiveMode(); // important!
            String data = "Test 09.06.2012";
            ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes());
            boolean result = con.storeFile("/FTPTest.txt", in);
            in.close();
            if (result) Log.v("upload result", "succeeded");
            System.out.println("Test ok ..."); 


        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    try
    {
        con.logout();
        con.disconnect();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pseudo code. I have not tested for syntax or any errors for that matter.

```
// in application never use hardcoded paths
File folder = new File("/sdcard/ftp/");
File tempFile = null;
FTPFile[] tempFTPFile = null;

//get all files in folder
for(String fileInDir : folder.list()){
    tempFile = new File(fileInDir);
    tempFTPFile = ftpConnection.listNames(tempFile.getName);

    if(tempFTPFile!=null || tempFTPFile.length<=0){
        ftpConnection.upload(fileInDir);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But where I should insert this part of code? At the beginning of the Avtivity? Sorry, I'm an absolutely newbie in Android programming.